# Searching /list with irssi

Tags: irc, irssi

I have installed grep.pl in my irssi, and try running `/grep foo /list`, however I just get the entire output of the /list command.
Grep does work fine with other commands, for example `/grep foo /window list` works exactly as expected.

Is there any way to search through /list?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do `/list`, and then `/lastlog foo`. You can clear the output from the `/lastlog` command by doing `/lastlog -clear`
2. Check if your network has a facility to search for channels (for example, on Freenode, try `/msg alis help`. Maybe try `/whois alis` to see if your network has such a service)

Comment: Tbh I've since moved on and stopped trying to use irssi myself, but thanks anyway for the response. Hopefully it can help others in the future :)